# Rearranging the rows in Datagridview

Tags: datagridview

**DataGRidView**

[image]

I have created a DKT Application . I have a Form called Question where i can add,delete,find,update,save and also a datagridview control to  do all these work. problem is when i delete a question it doesn't change the Question no . for example: if i have 6 questions and i delete question no 4.now i want to add 1 more question and then delete question 6 but it wont find the question no6. someone can help me please. if my Question is not clear please let me know. Thanks

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Question

Dim currentlyEditingDeleteingQueNo As Integer
Private Sub Question_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TXTQuestionNo.Enabled = False
    TXTQuestionNo.Text = gloTestQuestion.Count + 1
    Fill_Grid()
End Sub
'Insert a new question in array list.
Private Sub BTNAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNAdd.Click
    Dim question As Trivia_Data
    question.intQuestionNo = TXTQuestionNo.Text
    question.strQuestion = TXTQuestion.Text
    question.strAnswer1 = TXTAnswer1.Text
    question.strAnswer2 = TXTAnswer2.Text
    question.strAnswer3 = TXTAnswer3.Text
    question.strAnswer4 = TXTAnswer4.Text
    question.intCorrectAnswer = (TXTAnswer5.Text)
    gloTestQuestion.Add(question)
    Fill_Grid()
    MessageBox.Show("Question inserted sucessfully....")
    ClearText()
End Sub

'Clears all text boxes for next question and display possible question for it.
Private Sub ClearText()
    TXTAnswer1.Clear()
    TXTAnswer2.Clear()
    TXTAnswer3.Clear()
    TXTAnswer4.Clear()
    TXTAnswer5.Clear()
    TXTQuestion.Clear()
    TXTQuestionNo.Clear()
    TXTQuestionNo.Text = gloTestQuestion.Count + 1
End Sub

'Fills data grid view controls with available question in a system.
Private Sub Fill_Grid()
    'DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
    ' DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()

    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Question Number", "Question Number")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Question", "Question")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Answer1", "Answer1")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Answer2", "Answer2")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Answer3", "Answer3")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Answer4", "Answer4")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("CorrectAnswer", "CorrectAnswer")
    Dim question As Trivia_Data
    For j = 0 To gloTestQuestion.Count - 1
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        question = gloTestQuestion(j)
        DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells("Question Number").Value = question.intQuestionNo.ToString()
        DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells("Question").Value = question.strQuestion
        DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells("Answer1").Value = question.strAnswer1
        DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells("Answer2").Value = question.strAnswer2
        DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells("Answer3").Value = question.strAnswer3
        DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells("Answer4").Value = question.strAnswer4
        DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells("CorrectAnswer").Value = question.intCorrectAnswer
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub BTNFind_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNFind.Click
    Dim totalAddedQuestion As Integer = gloTestQuestion.Count
    Dim questionNo = InputBox("Enter the question number that you want to search:")
    If questionNo > gloTestQuestion.Count And questionNo = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Question doesn't exist........")
        ClearText()
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'gloTestQuestions. sort(compare)
        Fill_Grid()
        Dim max As Integer
        Dim min As Integer
        Dim mid As Integer
        min = 0
        max = totalAddedQuestion - 1
        While (max >= min)
            mid = (min + max) / 2
            Dim question As Trivia_Data = CType(gloTestQuestion(mid), Trivia_Data)
            If question.intQuestionNo < questionNo Then
                min = mid + 1
            ElseIf question.intQuestionNo > questionNo Then
                max = mid - 1
            Else
                TXTAnswer1.Text = question.strAnswer1
                TXTAnswer2.Text = question.strAnswer2
                TXTAnswer3.Text = question.strAnswer3
                TXTAnswer4.Text = question.strAnswer4
                TXTAnswer5.Text = question.intCorrectAnswer
                TXTQuestion.Text = question.strQuestion
                TXTQuestionNo.Text = question.intQuestionNo
                currentlyEditingDeleteingQueNo = mid
                MessageBox.Show("Question found.........")
                BTNUpdate.Enabled = True
                BTNDelete.Enabled = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End While
    End If
    MessageBox.Show("Question doesn't exist......")
    ClearText()
End Sub
'Saves questions in binary file and closes the file after writing operations.

Private Sub BTNSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNSave.Click
    Dim file As New FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() & "\Question.dat", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
    Dim fileWrite As BinaryWriter = New BinaryWriter(file)
    Dim question As Trivia_Data
    For i = 0 To gloTestQuestion.Count - 1
        question = CType(gloTestQuestion(i), Trivia_Data)
        fileWrite.Write(Convert.ToInt16(question.intQuestionNo))
        fileWrite.Write(question.strQuestion)
        fileWrite.Write(question.strAnswer1)
        fileWrite.Write(question.strAnswer2)
        fileWrite.Write(question.strAnswer3)
        fileWrite.Write(question.strAnswer4)
        fileWrite.Write(Convert.ToInt16(question.intCorrectAnswer))

    Next
    fileWrite.Close()
    file.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Questions saved in file successfully........")
End Sub

'Update existing question as per newly provided values.

Private Sub BTNUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNUpdate.Click
    Dim question As Trivia_Data = CType(gloTestQuestion(currentlyEditingDeleteingQueNo), Trivia_Data)
    question.strAnswer1 = TXTAnswer1.Text
    question.strAnswer2 = TXTAnswer2.Text
    question.strAnswer3 = TXTAnswer3.Text
    question.strAnswer4 = TXTAnswer4.Text
    question.intCorrectAnswer = TXTAnswer5.Text
    question.strQuestion = TXTQuestion.Text
    gloTestQuestion(currentlyEditingDeleteingQueNo) = question
    MessageBox.Show("Question updated successfully............")
    BTNUpdate.Enabled = False
    BTNDelete.Enabled = False
    ClearText()
    Fill_Grid()
End Sub

'Deletes a current question from the arraylist.

Private Sub BTNDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNDelete.Click
    gloTestQuestion.RemoveAt(currentlyEditingDeleteingQueNo)
    Fill_Grid()
    ClearText()
    MessageBox.Show("Question removed successfully......")
    BTNDelete.Enabled = False
    BTNUpdate.Enabled = False
End Sub

'Closes the question form

Private Sub BTNClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNClose.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What does your question have to do with VBA? I don't see anything related to VBA?

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong in your Find function :

```
If questionNo > gloTestQuestion.Count And questionNo = 0 Then
```

You muddle up the question id (`question.intQuestionNo`) with the question index in your array (`gloTestQuestion`).

Comment: Thanks Bioukh . But Can you please explain a little bit . Thanks again

Comment: You're asking the user for the _Question Number_ to delete. But in your function you're comparing the user _Question Number_ with the index in your question array. _Question Number_ 1 has index 0 in the question array, _Question Number_ 6 has index 3 in the question array...

Comment: Thanks a lot BIoukh. its been solved.Thanks again for your help.